# OSB shared variable between request and response

Tags: variables, request, response, uuid, osb

I am trying to generate a unique id using `fn-bea:uuid()` and insert this shared variable into inbound and outbound message.

But I do't know how to create a variable can be shared between request and response. It seems that I can not drag anything before the RouteNode, now I can only have two insert actions one for request and one for response. In this way there will be two different UUIDs. Is there any way I can create a shared variable and insert the same variable into request and response?

[image]

**Update:** 
I see if I put a assign activity right before the request's insert.(Screenshot 2) the variable created also can be used in the response insert activity. And I tested it, it is the same value. This works good. But I am having another problem here. I tried to use insert activity insert a the variable into inbound and outbound message. I set it to "as first child of" inbound for request and "as first child of" outbound for response. I can see the variable is successfully added into the inbound message, but the outbound does not work. Just for testing I try to set the insert to "as first child of" header for response, and output the header I can see its added successfully, means its working for header, but not outbound. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a variable with assign activity in request, that will hold your uid and use the same variable in response pipeline ?

Comment: You mean I could have a assign activity right before the insert action? That variable can be used in the response as well? And it is the same uuid?

Comment: I see what you are saying I tried it myself and it works, but I am having a problem with the outbound message, please see the updated question.

Comment: I understand that you created uid in assign and using it in both of your insert activities. Now,what is not working (Not able to understand that) ?

Comment: @Habin It appears to be, I can insert this into the request inbound, but not the response outbound. I tried the response header this still works.